# Ember JS how to set property accessible in all templates

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

This is a pretty noobie question but I searched for this over the internet in vain for many days now.

I am building an Application which has an Ember front end server connecting to a Node JS back end.
For development and testing both Node and Ember are running on my local machine at localhost:3000 and localhost:4200 respectively.
However some resources like images etc. are getting saved on the Node server and to fetch those resources I am having to hardcode the server ip in my template.
For instance 
`<img src="http://localhost:3000/"{{brand.imgLocation}}/>`

This is a nightmare because whenever I need to update to production server I am having to change it to Node Server IP in every place across all templates which is inconsistent.
Is there a place where I can store it as a property accessible to all templates ,I tried saving it as a property in Index Controller but it is not accessible in other templates except for Index template.

Comment: Use [environments](http://www.ember-cli.com/#Environments)?

Answer (score 1):

The Application Controller exists on every page. That would be the best place for it I think.

Comment: but I don't have an Application controller.
I am creating one now and giving it a try now.

Comment: It gets created for you in he background if you haven't explicitly created one.. If you want to edit the application controller, create it and make changes - then your explicitly defined application controller will exist on every page rather than the automatically generated one